# How to install Bob on Python3?

Tags: python, c++, c, centos, python-bob

I have installed all necessary dependencies on CentOS and Python levels and have thougt I'm near the finish but this is what I have got at the end. And now I have no idea how to make it work.

```
Installed /tmp/easy_install-3f76uq1w/bob.blitz-2.0.13/.eggs/bob.extension-2.4.5-py3.4.egg
In file included from /usr/include/python3.4m/pyatomic.h:8:0,
                 from /usr/include/python3.4m/Python.h:53,
                 from /tmp/easy_install-3f76uq1w/bob.blitz-2.0.13/bob/blitz/include/bob.blitz/capi.h:24,
                 from /tmp/easy_install-3f76uq1w/bob.blitz-2.0.13/bob/blitz/include/bob.blitz/cppapi.h:12,
                 from bob/blitz/api.cpp:9:
/usr/include/python3.4m/dynamic_annotations.h:472:3: error: template with C linkage
   template <class T>
   ^
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 126, in _compile
    extra_postargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
    spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in spawn
    _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/spawn.py", line 162, in _spawn_posix
    % (cmd, exit_status))
distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

It seems this error somewhere inside Python or its libs. And unfortunately I'm not so familiar with C, Linux and Python to fix it by myself. Also I haven't found any workaround in google.

Does workaround for this really exist?

I know about Anaconda and using Bob via its environment. But I need to cythonize my python app for calling it from C. And I'm not sure that it will work fine.

Comment: Can you post your python code.  The `import` portion.

Comment: If you mean import bob, it's just `import bob.ap`

Comment: So your only using the audio processing part of bob in your code right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Do you know Bob analogs may be?

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late to answer.

The version of gcc you are using might be old and does not support new C++ features.

Also about your concern on not using conda, you can use cython with a conda installation as well.

Please take a look at https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/install for the latest instructions on how to install Bob.